# Zend Message - read from file not from storage

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, zend-mail, email-parsing

Using `\Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap` I can read emails using `$storage->getMessage($i);`

The question is - is it possible (using `Zend\Mail`) to read message from string or file? I would like to write tests to test if e-mail is parsed correctly but at the moment I don't know the way I could create `\Zend\Mail\Storage\Message` without actually getting e-mail from storage but reading it from string or file.

Comment: Have you looked at [`ZendTest\Mail\Storage\ImapTest`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mail/blob/master/test/Storage/ImapTest.php#L263)? From my brief check on github, they [seem to use a plan-text file](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mail/blob/master/test/_files/test.mbox/INBOX) as you require.